# Papers on the history of the answers to Parmenides

Tags: history-of-philosophy, parmenides, zeno-of-elea

I'd like to ask if any of you know of a paper which talks about the history of the answers to Parmenides and Zeno(from Plato and Aristotle to more recent works such as Russell's and )

Comment: For Ancient philosophers, you can see Patricia Curd, [The Legacy of Parmenides (1998)](https://books.google.it/books?id=hW1hDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: For modern ones, you can see Martin Heidegger, [Parmenides (1982)](https://books.google.it/books?id=frwxZ3GWduYC&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Obviously, you can see SEP's entry on [Parmenides : Some Principal Types of Interpretation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parmenides/#SomPriTypInt)

Comment: More specifically on Zeno's Paradoxes, see Wesley Salmon (editor), [Zeno's Paradoxes](https://books.google.it/books?id=0AzP9WLLJLcC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: [Solutions to Zeno Paradoxes by Papa-Grimaldi](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/2304/1/zeno_maths_review_metaphysics_alba_papa_grimaldi.pdf).